# jsfeat function is not accessing

Tags: javascript, json, haar-classifier, jsfeat

I am working on JSFEAT but when I start using this library the function is not accessing.
resource at:

```
   <script src="js/inspirit-jsfeat-4f32787/build/jsfeat.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   var cols,rows,data_type;
   var my_matrix=new jsfeat.matrix_t(cols,rows,data_type);

   alert("2");
   </script>
```

Expecting to execute 1 and 2 prompts but only 1 is getting whereas 2 is not....
please help me in accessing it. Is it rightway???

Answer (score 0):

Add this script: jsfeat_struct.js